# How do I get the previous query or user input in LUIS bot

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Is there a way to find out what was the previous user input in LUIS? For example:

User: Get me my flight details
Bot: What is your email address?
User: Why do you need it?

In this scenario, I need it to access the user's flight details... so I want to be able to handle that question and still get back to the original thread of, like the example, retrieving the flight details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the dialogs in bot application work in a stack, so if you ask user question (for ex. email), you end up in the same dialog. I assume you're working with BotFramework as well. If you call:

```
context.Call(new EmailDialog(), ResumeAfterEmail)
```

The `ResumeAfterEmail` method will be invoked as soon as the `EmailDialog` is finished, and the local variables of the current dialog will be there as well, so you can continue with any action, having all the data.

In case you want to persist the data across multiple dialogs, you can use `UserData` or `ConversationData` like this:

`context.UserData.SetValue<some_type>(string key, some_type value)`

And:

`context.UserData.GetValue<some_type>(string key)`

This will be persisted for some time, depends on which `(...)Data` you use.

To sum up - saving the conversation data is not part of LUIS, you have to do in your application's logic. If you want to retrieve the exact queries or results from LUIS, just save them in local variables or in `context.(...)Data`.